# Callback function returning promise instead of the value

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, fetch, asynchronous-javascript

I'm using fetch to grab data from a json file. In a .then(), I call a callback to do something with that data, and then eventually return the final value from the callback. The problem is that, when I return, it returns a promise instead of the final value. I've looked through other similar questions, and thought I had the asynch concepts down, but I'm still stuck on this. Is there something I'm missing?

```
const func = (callback) => {
  fetch('https://asdf.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return callback(data)
    }
}
const callBack = (parsedData) => {
  //do something to get finalValue
  return finalValue
}

func(callBack);
```

I should add that, I tried just calling `callback(data)` without the return, but this just returned undefined.

Comment: Which function are you trying to have return a non-promise value? `func`, or `callBack`?

Comment: @NicholasTower I guess func() actually. I could unfold the callback and just leave the steps to get the finalValue in the .then(), but it returns the same thing.

Comment: It is not possible for `func` to return the final value. It doesn't exist yet. The best you can do is return a promise. Ie, the first line of `func` should be `return fetch('https://asdf.json')`. The remaining lines should be able to stay the same.

Comment: @NicholasTower I see. Yeah, that does return a promise. Is there any way to get the finalValue instead? Maybe from the callback?

Comment: Why use callback at all? It's redundant in this case. You can just use promises directly. 

```const func = (callback) => {
  fetch('https://asdf.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return callback(data)
    }
}

func().then(finalValue => ...)
```

Comment: @Phix that shouldn't matter in this case? Any promise chain nested within (and returned from) a `then` will completely resolve until it reaches the next `then` in the upper chain.

In this case `.json()` will resolve with a json before the next `then`

Comment: @nem035 Hmm, earlier I said I could unfold the callback and just leave the steps in the .then(), but this way still returns the promise instead of the value. This way doesn't use the callback, but still isn't able to return the finalValue. Also the code snippet you provided uses a callback, so I might be misunderstanding here. Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: My bad, it was a copy/pasta mistake, here's the right code: ```const func = () => fetch('https://asdf.json').then(response => response.json()); func().then(finalValue => ...) ```

Answer (score 1):

fetch method returns a promise, so you must use async/await or then() to make it works properly.
For example:

```
const func = (callback) => {
   return fetch('asdf.json')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        return callback(data)
      })
  }
  const callBack = (parsedData) => {
    //do something to get finalValue
    return parsedData;  
  }
  
 const main = async () => {
    console.log(await func(callBack));
 }

 main();
```

---

Using then():

```
const func = (callback) => {
   return fetch('asdf.json')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        return callback(data)
      })
  }
  const callBack = (parsedData) => {
    //do something to get finalValue
    return parsedData;  
  }
  
  func(callBack).then(response=> {
      console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the console log works, but is there a way to return it instead? Currently, it's returning a promise object, instead of the actual result.

Comment: How fetch function returns a promise, you must wait to the promise resolves to get the final value. So, the way you want it's impossible. What is the problem to use await or then() ? it's a common way to use stuffs like this.

Comment: @ternt No, there is no way to immediately `return` the value that the fetch response will bring later. Use `.then()` or `await` at the place where you actually need the value.

Comment: I've tried both ways, but I was still unable to return the values. I think you're right and it might be impossible to do so, but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks!